# What is the most effective way to exclude blank records in a SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run a query to return all rows that are not null. But, I am not able to get that done.

How is this possible? Please assist.

[image]

Comment: As you can see, those are *not* `NULL` values, they're blank. `WHERE EmailAddress <> ''` would suffice to check both conditions at the same time (assuming the blanks are true blanks and not, say, single newlines or other invisible characters), since comparing `NULL` with a blank is not true either. If the rows remain, select things like `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), EmailAddress)` to see the code points of the strings so you can check for other "blank" characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where ISNULL(EmailAddress,'') <> ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
where emailaddress is not null
```

Or, frankly, just about any other comparison filters out `NULL` values as well:

```
where emailaddress <> ''
```

Filters out zero-length strings and `NULL` values.